# When did Jesus first introduce himself as Son of God?

Tags: life-of-jesus, gospel-of-matthew

We read in Mtt 16:13-16:

> When Jesus came to the region of Caesarea Philippi, he asked his disciples, “Who do people say the Son of Man is?”
> They replied, “Some say John the Baptist; others say Elijah; and still others, Jeremiah or one of the prophets.”
> “But what about you?” he asked. “Who do you say I am?”
> Simon Peter answered, “You are the Messiah, the Son of the living God.”.

It is usual for people entering public life to introduce themselves
, or to get the introduction done by someone else. We see John the Baptist introducing Jesus as the Lamb of God (Jn 1:29). We also see Jesus reading from Isiah and introducing himself as the Anointed One ( Lk 4:21).  But Mtt 16 suggests that it was Peter who first acknowledged Jesus as Son of God, before which he  had been known to the public by other attributes.  My question therefore is : When did Jesus first introduce himself as Son of God ?

Comment: Jesus never does. The voice from heaven (that of the Father) declares him (at baptism and at transfiguration). On earth, Paul is the first to 'preach that Jesus is the Son of God', Acts 9:20.

Comment: I do know for sure that He declared Himself as the "Son of God" at John 10:36, "do you say of Him, whom the Father sanctified and sent into the world; You are blaspheming, because I said, "I am the Son of God?" I'm not sure if Jesus said He was the Son of God anywhere else in the NT. At John 10:30 Jesus literally says, " I and the Father, WE are one." We already know they are one in purpose but what Jesus is saying here is that He and the Father are one in nature or essence. When the Jews were going to stone Him at vs33 for blasphemy, why does Jesus bring up Psalm 82:6, the subject of Gods?

Answer (score 4):

In John 1:34, the context indicates that John the Baptist is testifying about Jesus after Jesus' baptism in the Jordan River. Before this verse, John the Baptist mentions that he saw the Spirit descend from heaven like a dove and remain on Jesus, identifying him as the one about whom God had said the Spirit would descend and remain. It is in this context that John the Baptist declares:

John 1:34

> And I have seen and have borne witness that this is the Son of God.

It is a deserted place, and the dialogue is directed towards very reserved individuals, including some disciples and passing visitors.

Mark 5:7 KJV

> And cried with a loud voice, and said, What have I to do with thee, Jesus, thou Son of the most high God? I adjure thee by God, that thou torment me not.

In Mark 5:7, a man possessed by unclean spirits acknowledges Jesus as the Son of the Most High God. The spirit fears Jesus' authority and pleads not to be tormented. This interaction underscores Jesus' power over evil spirits. The account continues with Jesus casting the unclean spirits out of the man, illustrating his compassion and ability to bring spiritual liberation.

But this scene is also restricted to the disciples of Jesus.

Mark 14:61-64 KJV

> But he held his peace, and answered nothing. Again the high priest asked him, and said unto him, Art thou the Christ, the Son of the Blessed? And Jesus said, I am: and ye shall see the Son of man sitting on the right hand of power, and coming in the clouds of heaven. Then the high priest rent his clothes, and saith, What need we any further witnesses? Ye have heard the blasphemy: what think ye? And they all condemned him to be guilty of death.

In the Gospel of Mark, chapter 14, verses 61-64, we encounter a pivotal scene during Jesus' trial before the Sanhedrin, the supreme council of Jewish religious leaders of that time. In this passage, the high priest asks Jesus if he is the Christ, the Son of the Blessed. Jesus' response is affirmative, and he not only confirms his messianic identity but also prophesies about his future exaltation.

In response to the high priest's question, Jesus declares, "I am; and ye shall see the Son of man sitting on the right hand of power, and coming in the clouds of heaven" (Mark 14:62, King James Version). This response is significant on several layers.

Firstly, Jesus claims to be the Christ, the Messiah long-awaited by the Jews. This confession is a bold and fundamental proclamation of his divinity and redemptive role. He refers to himself as the "Son of Man," an expression used by Jesus to describe his combined humanity and divinity.

Next, Jesus makes an allusion to Psalm 110:1, which speaks of the Messiah being seated at the right hand of God. By mentioning that he will be "sitting on the right hand of Power," Jesus is affirming his position of divine authority, equal to the Father.

The reference to the clouds of heaven is an image associated with the second coming of the Messiah, as prophesied in the Book of Daniel (Daniel 7:13). By using this language, Jesus suggests that his second coming will be marked by divine majesty and power.

The high priest's reaction is immediate and dramatic. He tears his clothes, a symbolic gesture of horror in the face of what he considers blasphemy. He then appeals to the other members of the Sanhedrin, stating that they do not need any more witnesses, as he deems Jesus' response blasphemous.

In conclusion, the passage highlights Jesus' open confession as the Messiah and Son of God before the religious authorities. His response not only condemns him to death in the eyes of the Sanhedrin but also points to his divinity and redemptive role, fulfilling the messianic prophecies of the Hebrew Bible.

Answer (score 3):

As a prelude to the public reading of Isaiah, to a narrow audience Jesus introduced Himself as Son of God at the age of 12.

> And when he was twelve years old, they [Joseph, Mary, Jesus] went up to Jerusalem after the custom of the [Passover] feast. ... And he [Jesus] said unto them [Mary and Joseph], How is it that ye sought me? wist ye not that I must be about my Father's business? Luke 2:42, 49

They didn't understand this yet.

To a wider public, He revealed Himself as the Son of God while reading the passage from Isaiah.  Here's the reaction.

> And all bare him witness, and wondered at the gracious words which proceeded out of his mouth. And they said, Is not this Joseph's son? Lk 4:22

Why ask if He wasn't Joseph's son?  What was Jesus saying exactly as He read Isa 66:1?  Because of what Jesus meant when He quoted Isa 61:1 within the context of other preceding Son of God proclamations leading to this moment.

At inception--
At birth--
At magi--
At the age of 12--
At His baptism--

And now, as He claims the same publicly.  He is the Son of God.

> The Spirit of the Lord GOD is upon me; Isa 61:1

That is the Trinity proclamation.  Within this context, "upon" means indwelt, part of, is permanently, rather than intermittently as in Old Testament prophets, kings, or priests.

So, to answer the OP, this is the public moment.

Comment: Thanks SLM. Both Joseph and Mary had been told that Jesus is the Son of God, at the time of annunciation itself. (Mtt 1:20 and Lk 1:32). My question is about revealing of  the same to the general public.

Comment: Fair enough, though at the Passover, it was Jesus revealing Himself.  But I'll add a verse or two after His baptism.